# GAE Soft Memory Limit

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memory-management

is there a way to catch the soft memory limit warning in google ? I am not referring to the Memory Exceeded Error of 300 MB but the warning message which appears when you cross 180 MB memory limit.

```
01-06 07:11PM 08.597
Exceeded soft memory limit with 247.434 MB after servicing 1 requests total
```

I want to catch this warning when it shows up in my code and start deleting some memory

Comment: I'm pretty sure the message is generated after your code stops running, and the instance is recycled after it's generated so you can't do anything to it.  But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No exception is thrown in your code when this happens - it's logged by the runtime after your request finishes executing, so there's no way to 'catch' it.